# How to raise my laptop stand

Tags: technology

My laptop stand brings the screen much closer to eye level, but not quite close enough. I want to raise it a few inches by placing something underneath, but I can't think of what to use. The bottom of the stand is a solid flat base 13" by 11".

Comment: Does the stand have a solid base, or does it have 4 legs? (A photo would help you get better-quality answers.)

Answer (score 3):

1) Old books (or, if you have any, old *phone* books). If they don't cover the entire 11x13 area, combine multiple books, each nearly the same thickness, side-by-side. Duct-tape them together so they don't slide apart.

or..

2) If you happen to have four unused hockey pucks: trim a board to the required 11x13 dimension and place it on to of the pucks, one puck at each corner. For additional height add another puck under each of the original pucks. Secure the stand by drilling a deck screw through the board down into the pucks.

Answer (score 1):

Use toilet paper rolls (in an upright position) to reach the desired height.
Make sure you use enough to make a stable base, maybe even tape them together.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of great Ways, all of which i have used or are currently using:

- Pack of printer paper
- Book
- Using double sided tape attach some rubber feet like that for
  furniture
- Piece of wood
- Build a box out of wood
- cutting board

Answer (score 0):

I use plastic foam wedges. Strong and light, they create the space I need under my laptop to keep it from overheating (laptop fans FAIL often after a few weeks). This material comes in sections that can be snapped off to accommodate your height requirement. They have adhesive backing if you want to affix semi-permanently.

[image: plastic foam wedges]

Answer (score 0):

Use microlinear actuators and a 3-position switch. They take up no space and can extend many, many inches.